# Storing a char n number of times in 1 loop

Tags: c

Given an array of numbers `[2,1,1]`
Given an array of chars `[x,y,z];`

Trying to create a char array that looks like `[x,x,y,z]` // put in char times its number in first array. so @index 0 char is x and value is 2 so put x x

I can do this using 2 loops but is it possible to do it only using 1 loop? to make things less complex?

Comment: You could use `realloc` instead of `malloc`, although whether this makes things simpler is debateable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can possibly, do this in one loop. I have tried to implement that, I hope I had done that in the rightful sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    int numbers[] = {4, 3, 2};
    char array[] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    char target[BUFSIZ] = {'\0'};
    for (i = 0; i < size; )
    {
        target[j++] = array[i];
        ++count;
        if (!(numbers[i] > count))
        {
            ++i;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("target: %s\n", target);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\Mine\C\test>build example
"Turbo C Compiler"
Turbo C++ Version 3.00 Copyright (c) 1992 Borland International
source\example.c:
Turbo Link  Version 5.0 Copyright (c) 1992 Borland International

        Available memory 4125804
target: xxxxyyyzz
"GCC Compiler"
target: xxxxyyyzz
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you need two loops - one for the char array, and one for each entry in the number array.

Say that `n_array` is the number array, and `c_array` is the character array and `array` is the final array.

```
int idx=0;
for (int cidx=0; cidx<C_LEN; cidx++) 
  for (int nidx=0; nidx<n_array[cidx]; nidx++) 
    array[idx++] = c_array[cidx];
```

As pointed out in the comments, you might need to allocate `array` as well.  The only way to do that accurately is to either count the number of entries you will need by summing the values in `n_array`, or by starting with the length of `c_array` and using `realloc` as necessary.

Comment: No, you don't **need** 2 loops. It's simpler, but doable in one loop. In fact, you're saying it requires **3** loops, as you mention a summing loop, but don't put the code in your answer.

Comment: @AntonH And how do you do so making things "less complex" as required by the OP?

Comment: I don't. I commented to OP that it is *possible* in one loop (it would require the use of `realloc` and `memset`), but not *less complex*. My comment to your answer was with the word **need**.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the code looks like when implemented as a single loop. As you can see by comparing with @Trenin's answer, the nested loop solution is actually the simpler solution.

```
int main( void )
{
    int numberArray[] = { 5, 10, 2 };
    int charArray[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    int outputArray[200];

    int inputIndex = 0;
    int inputLength = sizeof(numberArray) / sizeof(numberArray[0]);
    int outputIndex = 0;
    int outputCount = 0;

    while ( inputIndex < inputLength )
    {
        if ( outputCount < numberArray[inputIndex] )
        {
            outputArray[outputIndex++] = charArray[inputIndex];
            outputCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            outputCount = 0;
            inputIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done!  I agree that the two loop solution is easier to follow, but this is nice as well, and really not that much more complex.  Both of us glossed over the memory allocation, but I don't think that was the OP's original question anyway.